# php and mySQL database concurrency update

Tags: php, mysql, database, concurrency

Lets say I wanted to increment a counter in a database every time someone visits a webpage.

The database called 'example' looks like this:

|Name.....| Value..........| id |

===================

|count......| 5................| 1 | <---- 1st row

and the code on the webpage looks like this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", ....);
$q = "SELECT Value FROM example WHERE id = '1'";
$r=mysqli_query($db, $q);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$increment = $result[0] + 1;
$q = "UPDATE example SET Value = '$increment' WHERE id = '1'";
mysqli_query($db,$q);
```

If two people access the webpage at the same time, person A will fetch the value of 5 and immediately after that, person B will fetch the same value. They will both increment it to six and both perform the update one after the other entering 6 as the counter value when it should really be 7 since two people visited the page. How can I prevent this?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in one statement:

```
"UPDATE example SET Value = Value + 1 WHERE id = '1'";
```

so also no other task can change it between your read and update.

**Here your script**

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", ....);
$q = "UPDATE example SET Value = Value + 1 WHERE id = '1'";
mysqli_query($db,$q);

Comment: Precisely. An atomic update like this is significantly better than doing a read/write cycle that's just asking for race conditions.

Comment: but the line: mysqli_query($db,$q); would still be required.

Wouldn't the same scenario be possible If person A performs the update line and person B performs it immediately after that, before person A runs the line below?

Comment: @Jay - if you use only the Update the result was 7 in your question

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If i do not include this line: mysqli_query($db,$q);
 after the update, then the update does not show up in the database

Comment: @Jay - yes , you must execute **one** mysqli_query($db,$q);

Comment: @Jay, i have add the script in my Answer

Comment: Ok that's what I got. But after defining $db, going back to my first comment; isn't the script seen as two separate commands? What if person B visits the webpage and executes the first command before person A starts the second command on his end?

Comment: @Jay ?? But there's only one query here

Comment: @Jay - if you use the InnoDB Engine for your table there is a ROW lock and a single query is also a transaction. this means that the second process (user) must wait until the first process finished the query. if you use MyIsam there is only a table lock and all query must wait if one process execute a update, instert or delete

Comment: @Strawberry my bad I got it mixed up. I was thinking it was two queries for some reason.